# Django on a single server. Web and Dev environments with web/dev databases

Tags: django

In a couple of months, I'm receiving a single (physical) Ubuntu LTS server for the purpose of a corporate Intranet only web tools site.   I've been trying to figure out a framework to go with.  My preference at this point would be to go with Django.   I've used RoR, CF and PHP heavily in the past.

My Django concern right now is how to have both a separate '/web/' and '/dev/' environment, when I'm only getting a single server.   Of course this would include also needing separate 'web' and 'dev' databases (either separated by db name or having two different db instances running on the single server).

Option 1:  I know I could only setup a 'web' (production) environment on Ubuntu and then use my corporate Windows laptop to develop Django tools.  I've read this works fine except that a lot of 3rd party Django packages don't work on Windows.  My other concern would be making code changes and then pushing to the Ubuntu server where I might introduce problems that didn't show up on the local Windows development environment.

Option 2:  Somehow setup a separate Django 'web' and 'dev' environment on the same server.   I've seen a lot of different and confusing information on this.  Also adding to the complication is what I assume would be the need to have two database instances running on the same server.  Or, how could you have two different Django environments for 'web' and 'dev' and have them point to different db tables based on name instead of needing two different db instances running?

Thanks for any advice.   I'm actually having trouble relaxing and learning Django not knowing how bad this is going to deal with.    I could easily just deal with the pain of developing in basic PHP if this is too over complicated.  With plain PHP it's dead simple to have a '/web/' and and '/dev/' path and separate db's just by checking the URL or file path for '/web/' or '/dev/' (and then pointing to the right db for example - 'mytool_dev_v1' / 'mytool_web_v1').

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem:

1. You can run 2 separate instances of django in the same server in different virtual environments. You can configure them in a multiple ways: using environment variables or just separate 'production' and 'dev' config-files and choose which gonna be used.
2. You can use docker containers to serve different django instances. It is the best way I think. You can configure them in the same way: by the environment variables or multiple config files for 'dev' and 'prod' options.

If you want to serve 2 (or more) sites in the same server youll probably need to configure nginx server to redirect requests to the separate containers or django instances depends on the domain name or something else (url, for example).

As I know there is no problem to configure separate database for each instance. You also can run your postgres or mysql instance in container. The same way you can run nginx.

I can't recommend you to develop your app in the same server where production app is running. I convinced that development must going in the developer's computer, but yeah... Windows is not the best for django development, but it mostly works. Otherwise I can recommend you to use dualboot or at least VirtualBox with Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems like everything would be much easier if I could just get my hands on a 2nd server at work.  Of course the problem is the extra paperwork nightmare that would be involved.   I wan't to say, the corporate security compliance requirements and paperwork involved in having another set of servers took about 2 or 3 months of my time last year.   Everyone always talks about which framework is the best to use but rarely do you see anything about how complex or time sucking a framework is going to be to deal with when running it.

Comment: Well... I can recommend you to look at [this link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/#define-the-project-components). It's about docker-compose and django. Might be helpful in your case.

Comment: Thanks.   What's really annoying here is all the advantages and speed increases that something like Django would bring to the table, would just be eaten up by the more  complex installations and maintenance costs (in time).   With PHP, the installation took a few simple commands and upgrading PHP versions 5 times last year for mandatory corporate security compliance, resulted on 0 needed code changes.   What really saves more time?  A simpler framework with almost no maitenance costs, or a more complex framework with much more complex setup and maintenance costs?

Comment: IMHO it's all about expirience. If you know how to setup all this things fastly and automate - it's not a problem. The same stuff with maintenance.